# What was the original math operation after optimizing compiler?

Tags: ida, assembly, c, math, compiler-optimization

I'm pretty sure that original code was much simpler:

```
(((x + 16) >> 31) ^ abs(x + 16) & 3) + 4 * ((y + 16) % 4) - ((x + 16) >> 31)
```

Looks like division with remainder... Any ideas what this could be?

The code was compiled with Visual Studio 6.0.

Comment: I don't think the high order code could be simpler, it's isolating the highest bit in a 32 bit value. I can't think of any standard mathematical reason to xor the highest bit with the lowest 2 bits after adding 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have attached disassembler listing:

```
.text:004486EA 02C                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
.text:004486ED 02C                 add     eax, 10h
.text:004486F0 02C                 cdq
.text:004486F1 02C                 xor     eax, edx
.text:004486F3 02C                 sub     eax, edx
.text:004486F5 02C                 and     eax, 3
.text:004486F8 02C                 xor     eax, edx
.text:004486FA 02C                 sub     eax, edx
.text:004486FC 02C                 lea     ecx, ds:0[eax*4]
.text:00448703 02C                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:00448706 02C                 add     eax, 10h
.text:00448709 02C                 cdq
.text:0044870A 02C                 xor     eax, edx
.text:0044870C 02C                 sub     eax, edx
.text:0044870E 02C                 and     eax, 3
.text:00448711 02C                 xor     eax, edx
.text:00448713 02C                 sub     ecx, edx
.text:00448715 02C                 add     ecx, eax
.text:00448717 02C                 mov     dword_524CEC, ecx
```

The right answer is:

```
(x + 16) % 4 + 4 * ((y + 16) % 4)
```

It gets obvious if you assume positive x and y.

Usually IDA Pro detects such cases, but I think last two instructions were confusing for the analyzer.